# How do I modify thrust direction to match image direction in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

I have a spaceship image asset which was designed to be "facing" the +Z direction, with +X to its left and +Y going up. I want a SCNVector3() for thrust in the direction the ship is facing, so that if I add a force in the thrust direction, the ship moves forward. I found an article that told me that I can use `shipNode.worldFront` to get the vector that I want, but it doesn't match what I expect. I created the shipNode and gave it a rotation as follows.

```
shipNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0,1,0,0)
```

When I position a camera like this

```
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 10)
```

I see the front of the ship pointed at me. So far, so good. In touchesBegan, I save the thrustDirection and print some values. In touchesEnded, I reset the position and thrustDirection and turn the ship π/2 radians in the XZ plane

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    thrustDirection = shipNode.worldFront * Float(-1)
    print("touchesBegan.rotation         \(shipNode.rotation)")
    print("touchesBegan.worldFront       \(shipNode.worldFront)")
    print("touchesBegan.thrustDirection: \(thrustDirection)")
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesEnded")
    thrustDirection = SCNVector3()
    shipNode.position = SCNVector3()
    shipNode.rotation.x = 0
    shipNode.rotation.y = 1
    shipNode.rotation.z = 0
    shipNode.rotation.w += Float.pi / 2
}
```

Even though SceneKit displays the ship correctly (first toward me, then right, then back, then left, then toward me again,) the data being printed has some unexplainable (to me) but consistent values.

```
touchesBegan.rotation         SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)
touchesBegan.worldFront       SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1.0)
touchesBegan.thrustDirection: SCNVector3(x: -0.0, y: -0.0, z: 1.0)
touchesEnded
touchesBegan.rotation         SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.57079625)
touchesBegan.worldFront       SCNVector3(x: -0.25, y: 0.0, z: -0.899999976)
touchesBegan.thrustDirection: SCNVector3(x: 0.25, y: -0.0, z: 0.899999976)
touchesEnded
touchesBegan.rotation         SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, w: 3.1415925)
touchesBegan.worldFront       SCNVector3(x: -3.77489542e-08, y: 0.0, z: -0.124999881)
touchesBegan.thrustDirection: SCNVector3(x: 3.77489542e-08, y: -0.0, z: 0.124999881)
touchesEnded
touchesBegan.rotation         SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, w: 4.71238899)
touchesBegan.worldFront       SCNVector3(x: 0.25, y: 0.0, z: -0.899999976)
touchesBegan.thrustDirection: SCNVector3(x: -0.25, y: -0.0, z: 0.899999976)
touchesEnded
touchesBegan.rotation         SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, w: 6.28318501)
touchesBegan.worldFront       SCNVector3(x: 7.54979084e-08, y: 0.0, z: -1.0)
touchesBegan.thrustDirection: SCNVector3(x: -7.54979084e-08, y: -0.0, z: 1.0)
touchesEnded
```

The first data section looks right--and the ship moves forward as hoped, but the second, third, and fourth data sections have strange values for `.worldFront` given the reported rotations. In case 2 the ship comes toward me but slides slightly to the right. In case 3, the ship backs up toward me. In case 4, the ship comes toward me, but slides slightly to the left. When I've rotated through 2π radians, the ship is facing and moving forward properly again.

I've read all the articles that SO suggested as I wrote this and have reviewed the Apple SceneKit docs, but can't explain the behavior I see. What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the thrust direction needs to be the negative of the ship node's `localFront` direction converted to World Coordinates. I'm not good enough with the coordinate system math to understand why that is the case, but the following version of `touchesBegan` does work now.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    thrustDirection = shipNode.convertVector(SCNNode.localFront, to: nil)
    thrustDirection.x = -thrustDirection.x
    thrustDirection.y = -thrustDirection.y
    thrustDirection.z = -thrustDirection.z
}
```

The `nil` in the `convertVector` call says to convert to World coordinates. That piece of information actually came from the `convertPosition` function in Apple's docs. The doc page for `convertVector` only says *"No overview available"*.

NOTE that the `localFront` type property was introduced in iOS 11.0.